# extended assignment statements in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading, operators, overloading

How can I add extended operators(below). Generally speaking how can I implement such an operator (for example only one).

```
X+=Y
X-=Y


X*=Y
X\=Y

X%=Y
X&=Y

X**=Y
X=Y

X—=Y
X//=Y

X<<=Y
X<<=Y
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation. The operators in question are called "augmented assignment" operators, so the first place you should look is to put something like `python augmented assignment` into a search engine. Even without knowing that, something like `python operator overloading` should give you some relevant results.

Answer (score 1):

By implementing, for example, `__iadd__`. See ["Emulating numeric types"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) in the language reference.